# Why conditionalPanel does not work on first attempt?

Tags: shiny

In my shiny webapp I put some *conditionalPanel* in various *tabPanel* like this:

**On UI side:**

```
tabPanel("Loading & parsing samples", 
             actionButton("runLoad"),
             conditionalPanel(
                         condition = ("output.load_panelStatus"),
                         h3("Push to get some summaries of the samples loaded"), 
                         ...)
)
```

**On server side**

```
observeEvent(eventExpr = input$runLoad, {
...
      output$load_panelStatus <- reactive({input$load_panelStatus=="show"})
      outputOptions(output, "load_panelStatus", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
      print("Parsing process ends")
      output$console_output_pre <- renderPrint("parsing process ends")
  })
```

Strangely enough this worked perfectly up to some two days ago but now (even when I test it on my old source versions) I have to press twice the *runLoad* button in order to let UI showing the remaining of the output (the *h3("")* statement and all the rest of the output ...). 
In the meantime I only performed only some package update but nothing that should affect the shiny app... (at least I guess)

I wander if somebody else has met recently this type of problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on shinycssloaders. The new version 0.3.0. does not work properly

Comment: See https://github.com/andrewsali/shinycssloaders/issues/39#issuecomment-578755495

Comment: Can you try the latest github version from right now and let me know if it's fixed